# Serving remote files in nginx

Tags: nginx, azure

I have a storage account in Azure. I have files in a container I want to serve through nginx.

For example, I got an `index.html` and `app.css` located at `https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/dist/index.html` and `https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/dist/app.css`

I got a server setup to listen with nginx on '10.0.0.1'.

When I try to reach `10.0.0.1` I would like nginx to grab files located in the remote storage account. Here is what I tried with no success:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   keepalive_timeout 5;
   root https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/dist;

  ....

  location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following error message from nginx:

```
2016/01/04 11:37:59 [error] 2192#0: *13 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.0.0.10, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "my-machine-1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like this

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   location / {
     proxy_pass  https://core.windows.net/dist
   }
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not working. I assume I need some kind of url rewrite so that `http://10.0.0.1/app.css` becomes `https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/dist/app.css`

Comment: Can't you append it to the url? proxy_pass  https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/dist/ - Edited by answer above if it doesnt work double check the syntax and take a look at the error logs

Comment: Nope it doesn't work sadly. don't understand why though.

Comment: Does `wget https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/dist/app.css` work from the server where Nginx is running?

Comment: what do you see with tail -f /var/log/nginx/* ?

Comment: @amq: yes it works. I'm able to get it.

Comment: @Perdo: No special errors in nginx. just 400.

Comment: so, what do you have? What do you see when you open the browser? Do you have the same nginx error on the logs?

Comment: So i endup only letting proxy_pass and removing all other stuff and now it works.... strange behavior :o

Comment: Glad to hear.I must admit my answer was made in a hurry and just pasted something quickly. I edited my answer to reflect the working solution :)